# Flatten Django Queryset that is using select_related() and full join

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-queryset

my goal is to union two querysets, however, they only match columns after the first queryset has been joined with it's foreign key table. Let me explain. Say I have three models like this:

### Models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    extra_data = models.OneToOneField(Extra, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Extra(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()

class FullData(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Then I am trying to do something like this:

```
data = Data.objects.select_related()
fullData = FullData.objects.all()

queryset = data.union(fullData)
```

This returns an error of:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns
```

The two issues here are:

1. `data` does not get the columns if there is no related row in the `Extra` table
2. The columns from select_related are only accessible by doing `data.extra_data.age`, meaning the left side of the union won't have the same number of columns.

I want to utilize django, but it's not giving me the same results as a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Data LEFT JOIN Extra on Data.extra_data = Extra.id
```

Please note I am using sqlite which is why the above query is written with a LEFT JOIN.

Any thoughts on how I can get select_related() to return null values for rows in Data that do not have a one to one row in Extra, as well as flatten it so that the columns match the FullData queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that like this:

```py
data = Data.objects.annotate(age=F('extra__age')).all()
```

then you can access the age like this

```py
data[0].age
```